# How to prevent gradle JavaExec task exiting immediately

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle I have java and application plugins

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'
```

The project is a standalone webservice based on Jersey. If I use the installApp task, then run the resulting jar file (either with java -jar or by the generated start script) then the webservice starts and continues until I kill it.

If I use the run task then the service starts up as normal but then immediately the gradle task finishes, killing the process.

```
2014-04-23 10:12:09,927   INFO                      RestServer -                          start() - Started Grizzly and Jersey at http://192.168.10.106:9999

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.589 secs
```

**How can I make gradle wait for me to kill the process before continuing?**